# Animating content children in Angular (2/4)

Tags: css, angular

I have a component that uses the `<ng-content>` selector to pull in some content children.

```
<!-- label-expand component-->
<div>
    <ng-content select="[appLabel]"></ng-content>
</div>
```

So when a component creates an instance of this label-expand component like this:

```
<label-expand>
    <span appLabel>Some label</span>
</label-expand>
```

I would like to set up the label-expand component, when hovered on to play an animation of the content child with the `appLabel` directive where the text gets bigger.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'label-expand',
    //...,
    animations: [trigger('expandLabelState', [
      //This is the animation I would like to pass to the content child
    ])]
})
export class LabelExpandComponent {
     @ContentChild(AppLabelDirective) appLabel: AppLabelDirective

}
```

How do I pass an animation defined with the angular animation metadata in the `label-expand` component to it's ng-content content child? Or is this a problem that should instead be solved with CSS?